# What types of HMM are there?

Tags: machine-learning, hidden-markov-model

I can think of:

- Factorial
- Hierarchical
- Layered
- Nested
- 'standard'

[image]

others?

Answer (score 1):

I think your picture coming from [Murphy's tutorial on graphical model](http://www.cs.ubc.ca/~murphyk/Bayes/bnintro.html).

And all these models can be named as "directed probabilistic graphical model" or "dynamic Bayesian network".

There are two problems we want to consider on these types of structured models

- What is the structure (connectivity among random variables)
- What are the hidden variables (which random variable we cannot observe.)

One can use knowledge specify the structure or learn the structure from data, Examples can be found [here](http://www.bnlearn.com/examples/). Which variables are hidden usually comes from domain knowledge.

In sum, the name of the model does not matter too much. All of them are directed probabilistic graphical models.